# Possible to see network traffic even the site does multiple redirects?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'd really like to see what a site POSTs after I login and to which server it does it to.

However when I look in Chrome's devel tools while logging in, it clears the network log each time the site does a redirect.

Is it possible single step through the login proceedure, so I can see what data is POSTed and to which server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always persist the network state by clicking on the Preserve log checkbox:

[image]

That way even if your browser visits several different pages you can still see the network log.